# Soviet Russia components need identifying

Tags: identification, components

I have a KO D-8e Soviet engine which was made somewhere between the 60s and the 90s is USSR. I'm trying to bring it to life and need to find what are those 2 dead components in series. They have no markings on them, except a black dot at one end and my guesses are that they're either diodes or capacitors.

[image: Whole circuit]
[image: The coil]
[image: The component]
[image: The rough schematic]

Comment: What makes you think they are broken?

Comment: When i tested them i couldn't get any capacitance readings, no resistance(not a short, but just like there's nothing there), past those coils I couldn't get any voltage when i cranked the engine

Comment: Transient suppressor/TVS comes to mind. Do you have continuity though the coils?

Comment: Yes, there's continuity through the coils.

Comment: Can i just replace the TVS diode with a normal one?

Comment: Are you sure they are in series with coil or shunt?  http://tinyurl.com/yy356cug  Check your continuity and ground connections.

Comment: They're in series with the coil. If my research of the engine is correct, the secondary coil should produce ~12W at 6V. My ground connections are good, iI had one brake loose, but I soldered it back up.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 the diodes aren't connected to ground, they're just sitting at the end of the coil

Comment: OK then something like this? I don't know the magnetic variables.  http://tinyurl.com/y2lam747  The values I chose don't see much power thru the diodes. But this polarizes the spark to the plugs.

Comment: Yes, this looks very similar, but are they mandatory and can i put normal diodes instead of TSV diodes?

Comment: This was posted a day or two ago - same pictures ...

Comment: Are you sure that you draw the connection diagram correctly? The components look like in parallel with the coil, and they don't look as they are "power components" to be in series with power path...

Comment: @SolarMike i have it posted on mechanics.stackexchange with a way different question

Comment: @Ale..chenski They were sitting in series, the tape is just contacts at the end of the coil with only one end connected to the components while the other end is grounded.

Comment: @PotatoMan seems to be the same question - ie it is not working, how do Ifix it....

Comment: @SolarMike well,  technically yes, but the other one is more or less about the system as a whole while this one is just the identification of the components. On the other thread a guy suggested to post here for the identification of the components

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it turns out those components were working, but  my multimeter wasn't reading the voltage after them.(such a stupid mistake)